# Windows Explorer sort method

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for an algorithm that sorts strings similar to the way files (and folders) are sorted in Windows Explorer. It seems that numeric values in strings are taken into account when sorted which results in something like

```
name 1, name 2, name 10
```

instead of

```
name 1, name 10, name 2
```

which you get with a regular string comparison.

I was about to start writing this myself but wanted to check if anyone had done this before and was willing to share some code or insights. The way I would approach this would be to add leading zeros to the numeric values in the name before comparing them. This would result in something like

```
name 00001, name 00010, name 00002
```

which when sorted with a regular string sort would give me the correct result.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's called "natural sort order". Jeff had a [pretty extensive blog entry](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) on it a while ago, which describes the difficulties you might overlook and has links to several implementations.

Answer (score 7):

Explorer uses the API [StrCmpLogicalW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947(VS.85).aspx)() for this kind of sorting (called 'natural sort order').

You don't need to write your own comparison function, just use the one that already exists.

A good explanation can be found [here](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/05/346933.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

There is [StrCmpLogicalW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947.aspx), but it's only available starting with Windows XP and only implemented as Unicode.

Some background information:
http://www.siao2.com/2006/10/01/778990.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood it, Windows Explorer sorts as per your second example - it's always irritated me hugely that the ordering comes out 1, 10, 2. That's why most apps which write lots of files (like batch apps) always use fixed length filenames with leading 0's or whatever.

Your solution should work, but you'd need to be careful where the numbers were in the filename, and probably only use your approach if they were at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

for some source code.

Answer (score 1):

I also posted a related question with additional hints and pitfalls:

[Sorting strings is much harder than you thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127913/sorting-strings-is-much-harder-than-you-thought)

Answer (score 1):

I posted code (C#) and a description of the algorithm here:

[Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c/7048016#7048016)

Answer (score 1):

This is a try to implement it in Java:

[Java - Sort Strings like Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205020/java-sort-strings-like-windows-explorer/23249000#23249000)

In short it splits the two Strings to compare in Letter - Digit Parts and compares this parts in a specific way to achieve this kind of sorting.