# How to sort a list alphabetically FAVORING numbers

Tags: python

I have a list of files each named after a camera. In the Finder on a Mac, if I sort them by "Name" the first three are in this order:

1D
5D
10D

However, in another application, the same list of files is sorted like this:

10D
1D
5D

Notice the 10D moved from the bottom to the top of the list. I think this is because the the second app is favoring numbers over letters. It's like because "0" is a number it has a higher placement than "D".

In Python, I have written a script that accepts a folder of files and adds them to a list. But I need the list to be sorted the same way the second app sorts them, not the way the Finder sorts them. I think the solution might have to do with the `sorted()` function and the `key` parameter but beyond that I'm not sure what to do.

For those of you who want to see code:

```
myList = ["1D", "5D", "10D"]
sorted(myList, key=theSolutionToMyProblem)
print myList
>>>["10D", "1D", "5D"]
```

If I'm way off please tell me. Point me in the right direction.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/442429

Comment: I don't think this is just related, it's exactly the same question, except referring to Finder's natural sort order instead of Explorer's.

Comment: Unless you actually want _exactly_ what Finder does, on the specific computer you're running on, down to the smallest quirk, not just natural sorting in general… in which case I can write an answer using `PyObjC` to call the same CoreFoundation function the Finder uses.

Comment: @abarnert, OP isn't asking why Finder sorts the way it does, OP is asking how to sort it as the second application does

Comment: @wnnmaw: I know he isn't asking _why_ Finder sorts it that way… but I thought he was asking _how to do the same thing_. But apparently even that is wrong, in which case this isn't a dup, just a desperately silly question.

Comment: OK, I get why he's confused now, and it's not quite as silly. He _is_ sorting the values the way he wants… and then ignoring the result and printing out the original, unsorted list, which just happens to be in natural sort order.

Comment: This was a horrible question. I admit it. Everyone should down vote it. I deserve to lose points. Is there a charity I can donate my points to? How can I be forgiven of this programming sin? I didn't try. I just didn't try :(

Comment: @wetjosh: The dumbest mistakes are always the ones you can't find yourself, so you end up asking other people and then feeling like an idiot. That's how it goes. I once spent an entire wondering why my gzip-compressed JSON wasn't parsing at the other end which re-compressed the data instead of decompressing it, looking for stray braces and single quotes and so on before realizing that hold on, the actual input to `json.loads` is random-looking garbage, not the stuff I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `sorted()` (or `list.sort()`) return value *is* what the second app returns

```
>>> lst = ["1D", "5D", "10D"]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst
['10D', '1D', '5D']
```

Comment: Clearly not, since OP felt the need to ask the question

Comment: Hm, then the answer to his question seems self-evident.

Comment: never underestimate my ability to fail.

Answer (score 2):

As wnnmaw points out, you're asking how to sort things in the default sort order for Python.

I think your actual confusion here is that you're not actually looking at the sorted results:

```
myList = ["1D", "5D", "10D"]
sorted(myList, key=theSolutionToMyProblem)
print myList
>>>["10D", "1D", "5D"]
```

No matter what you use for `theSolutionToMyProblem` isn't going to make any difference.

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) makes a sorted copy of `myList` and returns it, without affecting `myList` itself in any way. You ignore that sorted copy, and print out `myList`.

So, you need to do either this:

```
mySortedList = sorted(myList)
print mySortedList
```

… or:

```
myList.sort()
```