# Importing from multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have completed some code to open multiple workbooks and copy data into one master workbook. I can't figure out how the code "chooses" which workbook to open first to import. Anybody have any ideas what is the method excel uses to select the files?

Comment: It would be great if you share the code..

Comment: it most likely follow the order of which you defined in the code..

Comment: i Could see that it is taking in the Alphabetical order of the file name

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442429/windows-explorer-sort-method).  There is a link in the responses to a blog which talks about Window natural sorting method.  Unless you specify in the code which files to open, VBA will normally open the files based on the natural sorting method.